# How to disable UIButton in tableview after called another UIVIew in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I have 1 `UITableView` has multiple UIButton (named is "**Open**"button with different tags) in each row, i set tag for them. Now, after click on any button in each row, it'll show a `UIView` (**detailView**). On detailView has 1 "Submit"button. I want to when user click on "Submit" button, "Open"button with tag selected is disable. How can i do that? I used this code :

Code to create tableview with mutiple "Open"button:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d,%d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        UIButton *market = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [market addTarget:self action:@selector(marketPressedAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

        [market setTag:3000];
        [market setFrame:CGRectMake(200, 6, 30, 30)];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:market];

    }

    marketButton = (UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:3000];
    [marketButton setTag:indexPath.row];


    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
    _tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 100, 0);

    return cell;
}
```

And code when click on"Open"button:

```
    - (void)marketPressedAction:(id)sender
{

    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    buttontag = button.tag;
    NSLog(@"Market button click at row %d",buttontag);

    if ([sender isSelected]) {
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Marketplace.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [sender setSelected:NO];
    }
    else {

            [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MarketplaceSelect.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
            [sender setSelected:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
btn.enabled = NO;
```

Try this one in button click method

Comment: When user click con "Submit"button on Detailview, Open button has been disabled, not disable "Submit"button

Comment: you can get tag of submit button and set disable while clicke on open button.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your "Open" button to be disabled after you click submit button, you should use delegates

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED :**
Change you `marketPressedAction` parameter `id` to `UIButton *` and write code of below

```
-(void)marketPressedAction:(UIButton *)sender
{

    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Marketplace.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MarketplaceSelect.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    /// Here set you image ////////////////
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myCustome.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [self createMarketPlaceForm]; // call detailView

    sender.enabled = NO;
    sender.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

}
```

Comment: marketPressedAction is called to show detailview,your code can not set disable for Open button. Thanks

Comment: @user2669713 where is Open button click method ?? write this code in this method.

Comment: - (void)marketPressedAction:(id)sender
{
   
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    buttontag = button.tag;
    NSLog(@"Market button click at row %d",buttontag);
    
    if ([sender isSelected]) {
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Marketplace.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [sender setSelected:NO];
    }
    else {
    [self createMarketPlaceForm]; // call detailView
            [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MarketplaceSelect.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
            [sender setSelected:YES];
        }
   
}

Comment: in Open button click method, i call a function to show DetailView, after user click on "Submit"button on DetailView,DetailView disappear and Open button is disable, but i don't know how do that?

Comment: Thanks it work but if i want to change another image not disable??

Comment: what do u mean ?? i can not understand.

Comment: Sorry but it can only correct for 1 button, another "Open"button is not correct

Comment: Because tableview has mutiple OPEN button, so your code can only correct if user must have click on Submit button. If user don't click on Submit button, OPEN button still disable

Comment: And i want if user click on Submit button, Open button has changed another image. How can i do that? Thanks so much

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35491/discussion-between-user2669713-and-ranju-patel)

Comment: first what you want ?? i can not get it, improve your english .. also i edit my code check it :)

Comment: sorry for my bad English, First  i want to change image for Open button after user click on Submit button. If user not click on Submit button, it do not anything. Thanks